# Python: Given a string s and an integer C I have to find the summation of difference of number of each alphabet and C

Tags: python, sorting

If number of occurence is less than C it should be ignored i.e. sum of max(number of occurrence - C,0).
for example if the string is aabbaacdddd and C is 2 then output should be 4. There are 4 a's , 4 d's , 2 b's so sum of(4-2,4-2,2-2) = 4 . There is 1 c but since C > 1 the difference is taken to be zero.

Below is my code.

```
T = int(input())
for _ in range(0,T):
    N,Q = map(int,input().split())
    s = input()
    #print(ord("a"))
    #print(ord("z"))
    for q in range(0,Q):
        C = int(input())
        m = [0] * 26
        for i in s:
            m[ord(i)-97] = m[ord(i)-97] + 1
        #print(m)
        ans = []
        m.sort(reverse=True)
        for i in m:
            if i < C:
                break
            ans.append(i-C)
        #print(ans)
        print(sum(ans))
```

I am getting a time limit exceeded in this. What would be a faster way to do this?

I would prefer a solution that does not use built-ins or a dictionary

The constraints are-
All characters in s are lowercase alphabets , 
T,N,Q < 10^5 , 
C <= 10^9 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work under the given constraints. Assuming the string only consists of lower and uppercase alphabets.

```
for _ in range(int(input().strip())):
    N, Q = map(int, input().strip().split())
    s = input().strip()

    frequencies = [0] * 26
    [frequencies.__setitem__(ord(k) - 97, frequencies[ord(k) - 97] + 1) for k in list(s)]
    # To get something like [4,4,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,....]
    counts = list(sorted(filter(lambda x: x > 0, frequencies)))
    # counts = [1,2,4,4]

    for __ in range(N):
        C = int(input().strip())

        # Find the index of the value just greater in counts.
        for i, c in enumerate(counts):
            if c > C:
                break

        if i >= 0 and i < len(counts):  # If i is within range. Print the sum from thereon.
            print(max(sum(counts[i:]) - C * len(counts[i:]), 0))  # Subtract C from the individual counts
        else:
            print(0)
```

And to answer why your code exceeds time limit.
You are iterating over the entire string `s`. Inside the `for` loop of the queries.

So if `len(s)=10^5` and `len(N)=10^5` you will make `10^10` iterations. Or `O(n^2)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any way to do this without using a built-in or a dictionary?

Comment: Yes thats possible too. Shall I update the answer then? Do update the question as well then with the condition that dicts are not allowed

Comment: Thanks that would help a lot. I have updated the question

Comment: @Archit I've updated the answer, replacing dict with a list and using ords as the key.

Comment: For the input aabbaacdddd if I put C as 10 it gives the answer as negative maybe the final line should be  `print(max(sum(counts[i:]) - C * len(counts[i:]),0))`. Apart from that it works fine

Comment: @Archit Right, good point, thanks. I've updated the answer.
Also, do consider marking the answer correct, if it got accepted in the competition.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First of all sorting is a no-no because that will push your complexity to O(n log(n)).

Make an array for taking the count of the 26 alphabets.

Then, count the alphabets in the string using a single loop i.e. O(n).

Go through your count array and apply the formula you stated above.

Overall complexity would be O(n), which I think what they require.

If you want to leverage all the Python power, then,

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter(T) # it will return a dict with counts of all unique characters
```

Iterate through the returned dict and you will get your answer.

But, I suggest you use the O(n) approach above. Your code will pass then.

Comment: The array m stores the count of all alphabets and I did it without sorting the string. Even if I don't sort the array m it still gives a time limit exceeded error.

Comment: can you give the problem link?

Comment: I figured out my mistake. For each query I was counting the number of alphabets which only needed to be done once. Once I moved the counting part out of the for loop it worked fine.